# How to fix a door scratch?

Tags: paint-scratches

Got a Black, Crystal Black Pearl, Crosstour. Just last night, I reckleslly backed into the parking lot, and front right door was scratched by the short stone wall adjacent to the spot.

I'm not cheap, but is it worth getting a new door or is there a more recommended solution?

[image]

---

**Update**

Just now found this one [website](http://www.automotivetouchup.com/touch-up-paint/honda/2013/accord-crosstour/) that claims to sell the right color "NH731P" for it, if not roughly the same. Then searched it on amazon if it's a universal color. So I found this [product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007RRSZQ0). Would you recommend it? Never used touch paint before, would I need sandpaper and other tools?

---

**More pictures with better Exposure**

Closer Look
[image]

Biggest Scratch (The bottom one)
[image]

---

### After Applying Touch Paint

#### Up Very Close

[image]

#### Up Close

[image]

#### From standing

[image]

Comment: We're talking about those four little gouges?  Are they all the way to the metal?  Or did you only get down to the primer?

Comment: @BobCross Yes, the short white line. Not sure how to tell, it didn't seem like a deep scratch, or have any dents.

Comment: Have you tried washing the car and trying some "cleaner wax" on those spots?  That's a combination of wax and polish that, with a little TLC might take some of those spots right off.  That might reveal where you've actually reached primer / metal vs. left some stone dust in the paint.

Comment: @BobCross it feels more like bondo than metal .... it was bought brand new (with only 17 miles) few months ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try buffing the door first to ensure what you see is not just transfer from the stone. Some of the top layer paint might be missing but you also might have some of the stone on the car and that might be what you are seeing here. Pearl is extremely difficult to repair, but good thing is that being on the door and somewhat lower than the top of the door, any touch-up you do will not stand out too badly.

Comment: Ended up going with the touch-up paint, turned out pretty satisfying. only those who creep close will notice it. But it's an odd place for anyone to choose to look closely. For results, see updated question

Answer (score 1):

Yikes. Your problem is that pearl is a doozie to match by a paint shop and it's almost impossible for non-professionals to do a localised repair on it. Best case is that you can take it to a body shop and they'll end up sanding down and respraying the entire door. If you can live with it, you may be able to apply a scratch repair product which will make the paint dissolve a tiny bit, covering up the exposed metal. You'll need to also apply a layer of clear coat. McGuiars sells an all-on-one scratch kit. It's not gonna look as good as a proper respray, but it will cost 10 times less.

As I said, your problem is that pearl is very difficult to repair.

Comment: Even if the whole door is resprayed the chance of the pearl matching the rest of the car perfectly is near zero.  :-(

Comment: Get some vinyl flames of something.