# Fixing Scratched Car Door

Tags: paint-scratches, scratch

My girlfriend parked her car and scratched. So we have a bunch of scratches on the right rear.
Pictures attached. It's a company car, she's very stressed out, pregnant and working too much and doesn't have almost any time to deal with the insurance and I can't help her with that, as I don't speak the language.
I am wondering if I can handle it myself (I guess to make it look good and not stand out too much), so I relieve her stress.
I realize this is likely a duplicate, but I checked
the following questions:

[100 Scratches, easy fix?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38754/100-scratches-easy-fix)
,and

[How to fix a door scratch?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7370/how-to-fix-a-door-scratch)

it wasn't obvious to me if it's possible to fix it by myself or not, as I'm a complete noob with cars and can't assess the level of damage to the paint from the pictures as well as folks here. So thanks for bearing with me.

I wonder if [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Sonax-1837597-320-100-Grinding-Paste/dp/B00103G2X0/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=m3+kratzerentferner&qid=1619177126&sr=8-2)
or [this](https://www.amazon.de/Scratch-Remover-Isolated-Scratches-03059410/dp/B00103AKR4/ref=bmx_7?pd_rd_w=86BK2&pf_rd_p=8188a454-79d2-46e5-a731-a1e2d46dd738&pf_rd_r=6RESACNHK01E474NPY3F&pd_rd_r=3a8bebbc-eac3-473b-853c-451b89dd3779&pd_rd_wg=PiRW8&pd_rd_i=B00103AKR4&psc=1) products would help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Minor dings are common even with company cars, minor cosmetic damage is most likely not a concern. You could make it much worse by trying to fix it yourself, maybe you should leave it alone.

Comment: A properly run company car scheme should  have its own arrangements for accident repairs, providing replacement cars if required, etc. But something as minor as you picture is just "if you use a car, then stuff happens to it" and they probably don't care about it. The point is, the car does *not* belong to your gf, it belongs to the company. If the company wants to fix it, they will get a professional to do it, not send somebody down to the local car accessory shop to buy a tin of spray paint and do it themselves.

Comment: I agree. It's a bad idea to fix someone else's car without their authorization.